# What does the Stone von Neuman theorem say explicitly?

Tags: functional-analysis

I fail to understand its meaning, since I have no background in representation theory.
Concretely speaking, if I know that $Q$ and $P$ are Hermitian whose commutator is $i$, then what can I say about them ? Can I say that in the $Q$ basis the $P$ operator is a derivative ?

Comment: Other representations are possible, such as the Segal-Bargmann space. So no, $P$ does not necessarily have to be interpreted as the derivative.